# Ghost letter Debug in package.json in VS Code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the `package.json` file in my react-native project, there appears a ghost letter `Debug`.

[image]

The information screen on low right is when clicking ghost letter `Debug`.

When running `yarn install`, here is the error:

```
PS C:\D\code\js\xyz_app> yarn install
yarn install v1.22.0
error An unexpected error occurred: "C:\\D\\code\\js\\xyz_app\\package.json: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 1253".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\D\\code\\js\\xyz_app\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

If copying the content of `package.json` to a text editor, then the ghost letter disappears. But When copying back to `package.json` file, then it shows up again. This ghost letter appears in other projects' `package.json` file as well. I may accidentally hit a key. How to remove this?

Comment: deleting lock file fixed problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this debug shortcut by setting `Codelens: Npm Scripts` to `never` in UI or by adding `"debug.javascript.codelens.npmScripts": "never"` in your settings.json file.

[image]